# Why does Zerg AI get stuck

Tags: starcraft-zerg, starcraft

Why does the Zerg AI player sometimes get stuck at the very beginning of the game and doesn't ever evolve beyond producing drones? This happened to me in StarCraft: Brood War, in a melee game against computer player(s). I'm not sure it is map-specific, but I'm pretty sure it happens on the **Big game hunters** map.

This is a mystery for me since I was a child, and now that I can understand some AI, I would really like to understand this.

Comment: Never really encountered this. Is this related to some specific difficulty level (custom maps)?

Comment: For what it's worth I have encountered this.

Comment: Map, I'm pretty sure it did happen on `Big Game Hunters`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is something we can really answer; we'd have to pull apart the source code to really get at the root of the problem, I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The AI gets stuck because it can't find a spot to place his spawning pool. IIRC, too many minerals or doodads near the hatchery can cause Zerg AI's building placement algorithm to fail. Unfortunately, I don't remember how I know this.